# Proof of a theorem about Baire categories

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem: prove that the set of $C([0, 1])$ functions whose derivative is defined at every point (and it is either finite or infinite) is of the first Baire category.

I have no idea how to approach this and would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I removed your last sentence because it is asking a separate question.

Comment: oo, exactly, thank you, I thought so that the Lagrange formula approach

Comment: @Chris Janjigian: Your Lipschitz condition comment doesn't take care of *and it is either finite or infinite*. (Maybe this part was edited in after you made your comment, however.) Also, being finitely differentiable at a point doesn't imply being Lipschitz on an interval. Consider $x^2$ times the characteristic function of the rationals at $x=0.$ (Continuous examples also exist by constructions involving things like $f(p/q) = 1/q^{2},$ defined to be zero at irrationals.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes thanks, I definitely did not think that through carefully.

Comment: @Demons94 sorry for the bad hint.